# JSF : how to refresh current workspace programmatically

Tags: eclipse, file, jsf-2, workspace

**EDITED**

I'm using `<p:uploadfile>` to upload a image into my project directory for my article, the upload is successful, but i can't view the image right away, but after refreshing my workspace it appers in my article.
**UPLOAD  methode:**

```
public void upload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    try {
        new FileUpload().copyFile(event.getFile().getFileName(), event
                .getFile().getInputstream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**COPYFILE methode :**

```
public void copyFile(String fileName, InputStream in) {
        try {

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(destination
                    + fileName));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
            while ((read = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            in.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

**.XHTML: [EDITED PART]**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <style>
.topAligned {
    vertical-align: top;
}
</style>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:tooltip  />
    <h:form id="form">
        <p:growl id="notification" showDetail="true" />
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="width:1220px;">
            <h:outputText value="Nos Actualités :"
                style="font-size: 30px;line-height: 40px;" />
            <p:commandLink title="Ajouter" id="add" onclick="PF('dlg1').show();">
                <h:graphicImage value="../img/add.png"
                    style="width:55px;height:55px;float:right;" />
            </p:commandLink>
        </h:panelGrid>

        <div style="margin-left: 25px;">
            <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                <ui:repeat value="#{actualiteMBean.actualites}" var="actualite">
                    <h:outputText value="#{actualite.titreActualite}"
                        style="font-weight:bold;" />
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" styleClass="topAligned"
                        style="display:block;" cellpadding="10">
                        <h:graphicImage value="#{actualite.imageActualite}"
                            style="width:150px; height:150px;" />
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <div style="text-align: justify;">
                                <h:outputText value="#{actualite.descriptionActualite}" />
                            </div>
                            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="float:right;">
                                <p:commandLink title="Modifier" id="modif"
                                    actionListener="#{actualiteMBean.redirect(actualite)}">
                                    <h:graphicImage value="../img/edit.png"
                                        style="width:30px; height:30px;" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                                <p:commandLink title="Supprimer" update=":form" id="delete"
                                    actionListener="#{actualiteMBean.delete(actualite)}">
                                    <h:graphicImage value="../img/delete.jpg"
                                        style="width:40px;height:33px;" />
                                    <p:confirm header="Confirmation" message="etes vous sur?"
                                        icon="ui-icon-alert" />
                                </p:commandLink>
                            </h:panelGrid>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                    <p:separator />
                </ui:repeat>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </div>
    </h:form>
    <p:confirmDialog global="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">
        <p:commandButton value="Oui" type="button"
            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-yes" icon="ui-icon-check" />
        <p:commandButton value="Non" type="button"
            styleClass="ui-confirmdialog-no" icon="ui-icon-close" />
    </p:confirmDialog>
    <p:dialog widgetVar="dlg1" modal="true" resizable="true"
        appendTo="@(body)" showEffect="slide" hideEffect="slide"
        header="Ajouter une Nouvelle Actualité" showHeader="true">
        <h:form id="form1">
            <p:wizard widgetVar="wiz" style="width:900px;height:500px;">
                <p:tab id="titre" title="titre d'actualite">
                    <p:panel header="Titre d'actualite">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="3" cellspacing="10">
                            <p:outputLabel value=" Titre :" />
                            <p:inputText id="tit"
                                value="#{actualiteMBean.nouvelleActualite.titreActualite}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Champ Obligatoir" />
                            <p:message for="tit" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="image" title="image d'actualite">
                    <p:panel header="Image d'actualite">
                        <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellspacing="10">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Choisir Image :" />
                            <p:fileUpload id="up" multiple="true"
                                fileUploadListener="#{actualiteMBean.upload}"
                                allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/" sizeLimit="100000"
                                description="Select Images" required="true"
                                requiredMessage="Image Obligatoire" update=":form1:message" />
                            <p:message for="up" />
                            <p:message for="up" display="Chargement reussi" id="message" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="descrition" title="decsription d'actualite">
                    <p:panel header="Description d'actualite">
                        <h:panelGrid columnClasses="topAligned" columns="3"
                            cellspacing="10" style="margin:0 none;">
                            <p:outputLabel value=" Description :" />
                            <p:inputTextarea id="desc" cols="60" rows="10"
                                value="#{actualiteMBean.nouvelleActualite.descriptionActualite}"
                                required="true" requiredMessage="Champ Obligatoir" />
                            <p:message for="desc" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
                <p:tab id="validation" title="validation">
                    <p:panel header="Validation">
                        <h:outputText
                            value="#{actualiteMBean.nouvelleActualite.titreActualite}" />
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <h:graphicImage style="width:150px;height:150px;"
                                value="#{actualiteMBean.nouvelleActualite.imageActualite}" />
                            <h:outputText
                                value="#{actualiteMBean.nouvelleActualite.descriptionActualite}" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                            <p:commandButton value="Valider" update=":form :form1"
                                icon="ui-icon-check" action="#{actualiteMBean.save}"
                                oncomplete="PF('dlg1').hide();wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [0], true)" />
                            <p:commandButton value="Annuler" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
                                action="#{actualiteMBean.cancel}"
                                oncomplete="PF('dlg1').hide();wiz.loadStep (wiz.cfg.steps [0], true)"
                                update=":form1" />
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </p:panel>
                </p:tab>
            </p:wizard>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>
</h:body>
</html>
```

**Images of the problem:**
[image]

**after  refreshing the project in eclipse and restarting tomcat :**
[image]

what i want is the result above without refshing project manually every time, is there a way to do it **programmatically**??

Comment: could you post your XHTML code please.

Comment: i just edited the post you have the xhtml, i hope it helps